# getting filesystem on windows with cordova file plugin for UWP

Tags: windows, win-universal-app, visual-studio-cordova, cordova-plugin-file

Looking to create UWP APP using cordova.

The App needs to scan file system to get list of mp3 files on device, the device may be a desktop pc with windows 10 or a phone.

However the Cordova is able to see the virtual path and not C drive or D drive on device.

window.requestFileSystem(LocalFileSystem.PERSISTENT, 0, onFileSystemSuccess, fail);

The winPath of the received FS object is something like below

C:/Users/{USERID}/AppData/Local/Packages/{AppNameSpace}_bzbj8h50hftv4/LocalState/

And this is root of the FS, can not move directory to C: drive, it is not allowing.

So Question is, does UWP or any windows platform does not expose Storage devices to Cordova apps? Or I am doing something wrong, as I am new to Cordova development.

Answer (score 0):

For full file access in a UWP app, you will want to add WinJS framework to your app.

The plugins are going to be targeted to cross-platform support, and mobile devices have more restricted file access.  Running on full Windows, you will have more capabilities available, but likely not supported by plugins.

Look at http://www.buildwinjs.com/ for WinJS.